# How to pass a variable number of MTLTextures to a fragment shader?

Tags: macos, metal, fragment-shader

What is the correct syntax for passing a variable number of MTLTexture's as an array to a fragment shader?

This StackOverflow Question: ["How to use texture2d_array array in metal?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46094672) mentions the use of:

```
array<texture2d<half>, 5>
```

However, this requires specifying the size of the array. In [Metal Shading Language Specification.pdf](https://developer.apple.com/metal/Metal-Shading-Language-Specification.pdf) (Sec. 2.11) they also demonstrate this type. However, they also refer to `array_ref` but it's not clear to me how to use it, or if it's even allowed as a parameter type for a fragment shared given this statement:

> "The array_ref type cannot be passed as an argument to graphics
>   and kernel functions."

What I'm currently doing is just declaring the parameter as:

```
fragment float4 fragmentShader(RasterizerData in [[ stage_in ]],
                               sampler s [[ sampler(0) ]],
                               const array<texture2d<half>, 128> textures [[ texture(0) ]]) {

  const half4 c = textures[in.textureIndex].sample(s, in.coords);
}
```

Since the limit is 128 fragment textures. In any render pass, I might use between 1..n textures, where I ensure that n does not exceed 128. That seems to work for me, but am I *Doing It Wrong?*

---

My use-case is drawing a 2D plane that is sub-divided into a bunch of tiles. Each tile's content is sampled from a designated texture in the array based on a pre-computed texture index. The textures are set using `setFragmentTexture:atIndex` in the correct order at the start of the render pass. The texture index is passed from the vertex shader to the fragment shader.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should consider an array texture instead of a texture array. That is, a texture whose type is `MTLTextureType2DArray`. You use the `arrayLength` property of the texture descriptor to specify how many 2-D slices the array texture contains.

To populate the texture, you specify which slice you're writing to with methods such as `-replaceRegion:...` or `-copyFrom{Buffer,Texture}:...toTexture:...`.

In a shader, you can specify which element to sample or read from using the `array` parameter.

Comment: I had considered that but then all of the source textures need to be the same size, which is not the case for me. For example, I might have an image that is 21,000 x 5,000 pixels that I'm representing with four textures of size 5,000 x 1,000 and one texture of size 1,000 x 1,000. Using a single texture is not possible because the maximum size is 16384. Smaller textures give me more granularity at determine which textures are "dirty" and who's mipmaps need to be regenerated. These textures are being filled in from an XPC service rendering arbitrary tiles.

Comment: Follow Up: By reworking my tiling engine and allowing for "overflow" in tiles so that I can get tiles of a uniform size, the use if a 2D Array dramatically improves performance and cleans up the code quite a bit. The Metal docs, WWDC videos and Xcode debugging tools are pretty good, but there's still so much to learn if you're not already experienced with low-level graphics.

Comment: @kennyc I’m working on something like this, trying render a really large image as tiles. Could you point out some resources for me?

Comment: @akshay It's hard to offer much guidance as this is a very broad topic with many different ways to go about implementing it. If you don't absolutely need Metal, then I would start by getting things working using AppKit/UIKit and ImageIO. A scroll view can be an arbitrarily large size. As the user scrolls around, draw the appropriate part of your image based on the scrollView's bounds. You could also use CALayer's in a scroll view and tile your image into smaller images that you set as a layer's contents. I'm using Metal in my pipeline and mapping image tiles to textures.

Comment: @kennyc I'm also using the metal to map the images to textures. But i'm worried about the recreation of all the visible textures in different scales, whenever the user zooms in and out.

Comment: You should take a look at how `CATiledLayer` implements panning, zooming and content scaling. That will give you an idea of one way to implement this. In Metal, it's common to use mipmapping to downsample textures. You can use Metal's own APIs for this, or build it into your imaging pipeline. See https://metalbyexample.com/mipmapping/